# Troubles running Polymer project in Dartium: Invalid URL

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I downloaded the Spark project (https://github.com/dart-lang/spark) and tried to run the widget examples.

After adding

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

to the entry page of the first example to make it work with Polymer 0.9.10-dev.x (I added `../` because the entry page is in a subdirectory in `example`) I get this error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL (http://127.0.0.1:3030/widgets/example/packages/web_components/platform.js:35)
```

When I copy this URL to Dartium the script is shown in the browser, so the URL is OK.

Any idea what could cause this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to add all relevant information to the question I found the cause and a solution:

I changed

```dart
<!-- BUG: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14382 -->
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="xyz.css" -->
<style>
  @import url("../../../packages/spark_widgets/spark_modal/spark_modal.css");
</style>
```

to

```dart
<link rel="stylesheet" href="spark_modal.css">
```

and the error message went away and the examples are working fine now.